# Unit test for a function calling another function using jest

Tags: reactjs, function, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I'm new to Jest and having some issues to write the unit test.
My function is calling another anonymous function with some parameters.

Could you please help me fix it?

```
const myFunctionToTest = (code, data) => (isValid, availableCodes, defaultValue) => {
    if(isValid) {
        const isAvailableCode = isEmpty(availableCodes) || includes(availableCodes, code);
        return isAvailableCode ? get(data, 'originalQty') : defaultValue;
    }   
    return defaultValue;
};
```

Here's the mock data:

### Mock data:

```
code: 'AB'
data: { originalQty : 2 };
isValid: true;
availableCodes: ['BCD', 'AB'];
defaultValue: 0;
```

### What I tried!

```
describe('myFunctionToTest', () => {
  test('it should return originally assigned quantity', () => {
    const result = myFunctionToTest('AB', { originalQty: 2 } , () => {true, ['BCD', 'AB'], 0});
    expect(result).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: *some issues* - what issues? The question lacks problem statement. It also lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , there are several functions like isEmpty that aren't listed.

Comment: isEmpty, get and includes are 'lodash' methods and we don't need to test them here. The issue that I'm facing is - 'Expected number but received function.'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.
This is what I tried!

```
describe('myFunctionToTest', () => {
  test('it should return originally assigned quantity', () => {
    const result = myFunctionToTest('AB', { originalQty: 2 });
    expect(result(true, ['BCD', 'AB'], 0).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```